# how to rollback kafka consumer polling

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka 2.2.0. It seems to me that consumer always commits and ignores the configuration

```
// Configuration
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 0);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

// read data
records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
// do some processing on records
// throw an exception and exit
// restart the application (actually I'm debugging under idea)
```

I expect that next call consumer.poll() gets the same data as I didn'd call consumer.commitSync() due to exception.